# Showing/Hiding Grid On Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

For one user I need to show a different `gridview` so my thought is to create 2 grids and hide them both, and on `Page_Load()` show the appropriate `gridview` based off the userid.  This works, but it is quite repetitive since the 2 grids are very similar.  Is their a better way to achieve this or a more syntactically appropriate way?

Further Info - the for everyone grid has 16 fields
The YouOnly grid shares the same 16 but 4 additional fields is the only difference

**HTML** (just sampling of data)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="TextTopOfPage" runat="server">This is the top of the page</div>
        <br />
        <div id="Alldiv" runat="server">
            <asp:GridView ID="ForAll" runat="server" visible="false"/>
        </div>
        <div id="YouOnlyDiv" runat="server">
            <asp:GridView ID="YouOnly" runat="server" Visible="false" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**C#**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (userid == "eac11") { this.YouOnly.Visible = true; }
    if (userid != "eac11") { this.ForAll.Visible = true; }
}
```

Comment: Can you filter data that is used to bind to Grid based on userid?

Comment: @GrantWinney - the actual syntax for the grid is to show 16 fields, and the only difference is if userid is eac11 it shows 20 fields (exact same 16 as above with 4 additional)

Comment: @rs - I have never done such.  I will google to see if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the column definitions for all twenty columns in the ASPX.  For the four special columns, change the visibility of the column based on the YouOnly property.  You could likewise do it in the code behind using the OnDataBinding event.

Comment: Performance wise does it make a diff if I change visibility from html or C#

Comment: I doubt it.  The ASPX gets precompiled to C# before being executed.